# Playstation 3 fan noise due to broken sensor?

Tags: ps3, hardware, hard-drive

I've had a 60GB Playstation 3 model since 2007. It got replaced by Sony because of YLOD a few years back. For as long as I can remember the fans goes up to full-speed whatever the console is doing. The noise is the same if it's playing the latest game or is just in the XMB.

So I decided today that I should open up the machine and remove all the dust. So I opened it up and when I got to the big fan, there were almost no dust at all. I closed it and started it up again and the noise is still there.

Could it be so simple that a heat sensor is broken? The HDD has been replaced a number of times so maybe if there is a heat sensor at the HDD that I can replace? Can that be the problem that causes the fan to go to full-speed and make all that noise?

Comment: probably loose ball bearings on the fan itself. also, how "noisy" is noisy?

Comment: "Jet engine"-noisy. Full-speed direct at start

Comment: It's possible that the sensor broke, but I doubt it, I've never seen that before.  More likely the thermal paste has degraded.

Comment: Can you clarify *It got replaced by Sony because of YLOD a few years back.* part? So you now have other (new) console or what?

Comment: I actually don't know if it's a new one or if they replaced some parts in it but I got back a working (fat) backwards compatible PS3 from Sony.